# Atiyah's paper on complex structures on $S^6$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology, index-theory

M. Atiyah has posted a preprint on arXiv on the non-existence of complex structure on the sphere $S^6$.

https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.09366

It relies on the topological $K$-theory $KR$ and in particular on the forgetful map from topological complex $K$-theory to $KR$.

Question: what are the nice references to learn about $KR$?

**Edit :** Thank you very much for the comments and suggestions, M. Atiyah's paper "K-theory and reality." Quart. J. Math., Oxford (2),
17 (1966),367-86 is a fantastic paper. However I have more questions.

Question 1: how to build the morphism
$$KSp(\mathbb{R}^6)\rightarrow K^{7,1}(pt)?$$

Question 2: why do we use $\mathbb{R}^{7,1}$?

In fact I do not understand the sentence "The 6-sphere then appears
naturally as the base of the light-cone". And why it suffices to look at this particular model of $S^6$.

Comment: It looks like you implicitly do not accept Atiyah's reference [1] in his paper.  What isn't "nice" about that?

Comment: I am reading [1], it is beautifully written. However as I am a complete amateur, I would like to understand the relationships between topological complex K-theory and KR-theory. In particular this sentence:
"There are natural forgetful maps from complex K-theory to KR-theory and in dimension 6 the integers go to 0".

Comment: The forgetful map appears to be that you can treat a complex bundle as a real bundle, that gives your map from complex k-theory to this "KR" variant.  Where is the sentence you are quoting?

Comment: This sentence is on p4 of Atiyah's preprint.

Comment: The integers he's talking about is 6-dimensional complex k-theory of $S^6$, i.e. this group is infinite cyclic.

Comment: Yes of course, but do you know why it is trivial?

Comment: I think it's just a straight-forward computation, isn't it?  I've only scanned the paper and this is my first time thinking about $KR$, but I suspect what's going on is that the generator for complex k-theory is the bundle with Euler class $1$.  In $KR$ theory this is twice the generator, because the generator is one where the fixed-point set of the involution is a Moebius bundle.   I haven't thought about this in detail but that's what I *suspect* is going on.

Comment: @RyanBudney Can you explain a little bit more how to treat a complex bundle as a real bundle? You need to throw in a C_2-action and I really don't see how to do that (this is a bit embarassing because I should know KR very well).

Comment: @DenisNardin You go from $E$ to $E \oplus \overline{E}$; your involution is the obvious one that swaps factors.

Comment: And the involution on the base space would be trivial.

Comment: I think basics of $KR$ theory is easy to learn from [1]. What is puzzling is the claim on p.5 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.09366 that "Because of the Atiyah-Singer theory, the linear algebra acquires a topological meaning, and that is embodied in $KR$ theory."

Comment: Karoubi briefly treats KR-theory in "K-Theory: An Introduction" (page 177). The book is a good reference for K-Theory in general.

Comment: @RyanBudney I suspect that the sentence "integers goes to 0" means integrable ACS goes to 0 in KR, while non-integrable ones goes to 1. It seems that he was using this map to separate integrable and non-integrable ACSs, it cannot be done if it is trivial. I feel that this might be the most crucial step, but do not have a clear idea what's going on...

Comment: For your final question, the section titled "Ambient Space Construction" on [this blog entry of mine](https://williewong.wordpress.com/2009/10/26/conformal-compactification-of-space-time/#more-105) is related. Basically it is a way to fix _one_ conformal structure on $\mathbb{S}^6$.

Comment: Regarding the map you wish to understand, I think that the KSp should be seen as coming from one specific KR. Btw https://web.archive.org/web/20230113145507/https://www.math.umd.edu/~jmr/NCGOA13.pdf should be rather useful, but I haven't been able to figure out the dimension correctly from there. Rosenberg uses a different grading to Atiyah.