# What is the current understanding regarding complex structures on the 6-sphere?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology, index-theory

In October 2016, Atiyah famously posted a preprint to the arXiv, ["The Non-Existent Complex 6-Sphere"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.09366) containing a very brief proof $S^6$ admits no complex structure, which I immediately read and realized I lacked the background to understand. The preprint inspired interest in KR-theory and a few postings on MathOverflow ([Atiyah's paper on complex structures on $S^6$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253577/atiyahs-paper-on-complex-structures-on-s6); https://mathoverflow.net/a/253490/5792), but a Google search does not seem to turn up any exposition or commentary later than November. A paper so brief on such an important topic has, however, no doubt been thoroughly read and reread by competent experts since that time.

1. Has an exposition with more detail been published anywhere?
2. Is the argument of the paper currently thorougly understood? If not,
3. What parts are currently understood?
4. What remains to be more closely explained?

Comment: The consensus among the experts I have spoken to is that the proof is incorrect.  For instance, it does not use the fact that the almost complex structure is integrable in a serious way.

Comment: Note that further complicating matters is of course the existence of claimed proofs of results in the other direction.

Comment: Well, that's disappointing, then. If it is indeed wrong, is there any hint at which step there's an error?

Comment: Andy, can you say more about why lack of use of the integrability would tend to indicate a problem with the proof? Why is it essential that would come in? (This does remind me though that Andrew Casson once told me that the first thing he did when he saw a claimed proof of the Poincare conjecture was look to see if it actually used the simple-connectedness. But of course in that case the simple connectivity basically is the hypothesis.)

Comment: @GregFriedman:  It is well-known that the 6-sphere admits an almost complex structure, but the known ones are not integrable, so the problem is to determine whether there is an *integrable* one.  Thus, it would be essential to use the integrability hypothesis to address the problem.

Comment: @SamHopkins:  Unfortunately, recent claims of existence of integrable complex structures on the 6-sphere have known serious problems.  One such claim (actually published) does not provide convincing justification that the claimed construction works (or even enough detail to actually specify the 'construction' completely), another makes claims that are demonstrably false.

Comment: @RobertBryant There is this claim in Atiyah's paper that an integrable complex structure is _even_. Do you understand what that means and why it is true? This seems to be the only reference to integrability at all.

Comment: @SebastianGoette:  In the most recent version that I have seen, the attempts to define *even* and *odd* were unconvincing and seemed to be mixing two different concepts.  In any case, the assertion that an integrable almost complex structure would necessarily be even is made without any supporting evidence that I can detect.

Comment: Here is Atiyah’s argument: there exists a differential operator on a complex sphere. If it is integrable, the operator is even. But the symbol of the operator depends only on the almost complex structure, and can be computed to be odd. The problem with the argument is the first step: he does not say what the differential operator is. I would file this under "not an argument."

Comment: It appears that Atiyah has published another (attempt at a) proof in an article which is *not* on arXiv, but appears in the book "[Foundations of Mathematics and Physics One Century after Hilbert](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783319648125)", which was very recently released.