# Atiyah's paper "Non-existent complex 6-sphere"

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology

I'm trying to understand the main idea of Atiyah's proof (https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.09366). Although there were discussions on MO year ago I couldn't find answers to my questions.

Consider the isomorphism on the 4th page:
"$KSp(\mathbb{R}^6) \rightarrow KR^{(7,1)}(pt) = \mathbb{Z}_2$"

My questions are as follows:

1) Atiyah says that the $KSp(\mathbb{R}^6)$ is "the stable homotopy group determined by Bott". But as far as I understand $KSp(\mathbb{R}^6)$ is the K-theory of vector bundles over base space $B$, s.t. the isomorphisms from definition of vector bundle $\pi^{-1}(b) \mapsto \{b\} \times \mathbb{R}^n$ lie in sympletic group $Sp(n)$. How is it connected with each other? Or how should I think about $KSp(\mathbb{R}^6)$?

2)Moreover, after that Atiyah claims that $KSp(\mathbb{R}^6)$ is "just the reduced $KSp$ of $\mathbb{S}^6$". How could one see it?

3)Next, Atiyah says that "There are natural forgetful maps from complex K-theory to KR theory and in dimension 6 the integers go to 0, so a hypothetical **complex
structure** on $\mathbb{S}^6$" would **give an even** element. But we know one **almost
complex structure** J(0) which **is odd**..."
Here I can't understand the meaning of "even and odd". In what terms should I talk about it?

I will be grateful if someone makes these things more clear to me. Anyway, is this proof accepted as true in math society?

Comment: Links to past MO discussions: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1973/, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253577/, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263301/

Comment: You should regard that paper as a sketch of a claimed proof that has not since appeared.

Comment: The last question "is this proof accepted as true in math society" makes a duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263301/. I'd suggest to stick to questions 1,2,3.

Comment: I'm going out on a limb and say that the paper does not contain an actual proof. I don't know whether the author plans to publish a follow up with more details or not, but for now I still consider the problem open.

Comment: @YCor, ok, I asked the last question only to have an updated information. However, first three questions might be still open.

Comment: Honestly I cannot even see which part of Atiyah's argument would supposedly use that the almost complex structure is integrable.

Comment: (1) Part of Bott periodicity is that $\Omega^4(\mathbb{Z}\times BO)=\mathbb{Z}\times BSp$ and $\Omega^4(\mathbb{Z}\times BSp)=\mathbb{Z}\times BO$, so $KSp$ is the same as $KO$ up to a shift.  (2) Atiyah is implicitly using $K$-theory with compact supports, for which $K(U)=\widetilde{K}(U\cup\{\infty\})$ almost by definition.  And $S^6\simeq\mathbb{R}^6\cup\{\infty\}$.

Comment: It appears that Atiyah has published another (attempt at a) proof in an article which is *not* on arXiv, but appears in the book "[Foundations of Mathematics and Physics One Century after Hilbert](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783319648125)", which was very recently released.